# How to separate 4th order transfer function (Butterworth Approximation) into 2nd order using Python Control Library?

Tags: transfer-function, programming, python, butterworth

Previously I had the following coefficients in the program. In this program I want to create a transfer function of butterworth approximation (Digital Filter Design - Digital Signal Processing).

```python
import control as ct 
import numpy as np

# Coefficients
b1_0 = 0.906197420861457
b1_1 = 2.1877541036312493
b2_0 = 1.401865445882832
b2_1 = 1.4018654458828321

# Numerator
numerator = [b2_0 * b2_1]

# Denominator
den1 = [1, b2_0, b1_0] # Denominator 1
den2 = [1, b2_1, b1_1] # Denominator 2

# Convolve the two denominators to get the final denominator
final_den = np.convolve(den1, den2)

# Create the transfer function.
tf = ct.tf(numerator, final_den)
print("\nH_B4(S) = ", tf)
```

Here is the output of my program:

$$H_{B,4}(s) = \frac{1.965}{S^{4}+2.804S^{3}+5.059S^{2}+4.337S+1.983}$$

The end goal is that I want to create a transfer function with format like this.

$$H_{B,4}(s) = \frac{\Pi_{m} B_{2m}}{\Pi_{m}(S^2 + B_{1m}S + B_{2m})}$$

$$H_{B,4}(s) = \frac{B_{2,0}B_{2,1}}{(S^2 + B_{1,0}S + B_{2,0})(S^2 + B_{1,1}S + B_{2,1})}$$

$$H_{B,4}(s) = \frac{(1.4019)(1.4019)}{(S^2 + 0.9062S + 1.4019)(S^2 + 2.1878S + 1.4019)}$$

However, with my code, the results are always multiplied and cannot match the goal.

Does anyone have a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the solution to this problem uses the simple solution of using the print function to print it manually.

```python
# Displaying the factorization result of the Transfer Function
print("Transfer Function (Form 2 - Order 2)\n")

print("\nH_B3(S) = ")
print(f"                ({b2_0:.4f})({b2_1:.4f})")
print("---------------------------------------------------")
print(f"(s^2 + {b1_0:.4f}s + {b2_0:.4f})(s^2 + {b1_1:.4f}s + {b2_1:.4f})")


Output
H_B3(S) =
                (1.4019)(1.4019)
---------------------------------------------------
(s^2 + 0.9062s + 1.4019)(s^2 + 2.1878s + 1.4019)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a polynomial of order 4 then you can compute the roots (e.g. with numpy roots). If the roots are complex they always come in pairs of complex conjugates and you can multiply these 2 together to get a polynomials of degree 2. This way you  can always split it up.

I do not think the "control" package has this functionality built in but the scipy.signal has: scipy.signal.tf2sos

[scipy.signal.tf2sos](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.tf2sos.html)

Using the tf2sos with your example:

```
sos=signal.tf2sos(numerator, final_den, analog=True)
n1=sos[0,0:3]
n2=sos[1,0:3]
d1=sos[0,3:]
d2=sos[1,3:]

# where n1,d1 then is
# array([0.        , 0.        , 1.96522673])
# array([1.        , 1.40186545, 2.1877541 ])
#
# and n2,d2 is
# array([0., 0., 1.])
# array([1.        , 1.40186545, 0.90619742])
#
# to print it nicely as formular you can use smypy
import sympy as sym
s=sym.symbols("s")
svec=[s*s,s,1]
print(1/sum(d1*svec)*n1[2])
print(1/sum(d2*svec)*n2[2])
```

$$  \frac{1.96522672836027}{1.0 s^{2} + 1.40186544588284 s + 2.18775410363125} $$

$$ \frac{1.0}{1.0 s^{2} + 1.40186544588283 s + 0.906197420861458} $$

Comment: I've tried it but when I use the tf function I can't display the output as I want. That's the problem.

Comment: if the output is the issue: so you could output each of the individual transfer functions seperately?

Comment: Yes, that might be one solution. But I'm still curious if it's possible to use an existing function to do it. Because my teacher said the same thing as you, which is using the roots function but I still got inappropriate results.

Oke, I will try using scipy package.

Comment: sym.symbols from which library?

Comment: from sympy. i will edit the answer to include it.

Comment: Ah i see. Oke thank you